# How do I deploy only certain parts of an app to SAP Cloud Platform?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, ui5-tooling, sap-business-application-studio

I've imported an existing SAPUI5 app into SAP Web IDE and wish to deploy it to <del>Hana Cloud Platform (HCP)</del> <del>SAP Cloud Platform (SCP)</del> SAP Business Technology Platform (SAP BTP).

Unfortunately the structure is not just one app, rather 3 apps within a parent app folder.

When I deploy to <del>HCP</del> <del>SCP</del> SAP BTP, it simply picks up the first app and ignores the other 2.

Can any of the config files (`neo-app.json` etc) be changed to allow specific folders to be deployed?

Comment: Apparently Web IDE can't deploy subfolders explicitly. Each root folder is considered as one application and deployed as a whole. Moreover, it appears that folder exclusion in Project properties does not work. So it will build all the files and folders.

Comment: Any more details of "Folder Exclusion" ?

Comment: @AdamHarkus: Found any solution.?